# MDTopAppBar strange height behaviour

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to build my first app but I have a problem with a MDTopAppBar.

Here's a snippet of what the code looks like

```
MDScreen:

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "Dashboard"
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 4
        md_bg_color: "232D3F"
        specific_text_color: "#008170"
        left_action_items:
            [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
        right_action_items:
            [['logout', lambda x: app.logout()]]

    MDNavigationLayout:
    
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            MDScreen:
              ...
```

On my PC it works fine, but when I switch to the phone, it seems that the text and icons are not aligned correctly. Here's two screenshots of the problem

- pc https://prnt.sc/2MxYCtSvxV8I
- phone https://prnt.sc/Qmf0YwT-ToSR

Following some tips that I found online, I tried to move the MDTopAppBar inside the MDNavigationLayout but the problem was still there. I also tried to write something like `size_hint_y: None, height: dp(60)` but also did not work